# Workbox background sync - Access replayed API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin, background-sync

I am using the Workbox GenerateSW plugin and using the backgroundSync option under runtimeCaching . Check docs here - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.generateSW

The plugin lets me listen to APIs and replay a failed API request perfectly.

However, after the API is replayed on 'sync' event, I need access to the API response since I want to update the UI state based on that.  Workbox  makes the API request on browser `sync` event. I don't see an event that lets me see when the API call has finished.

Has anyone else been able to access the API response?

Comment: Did you find any track ?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a plugin to achieve this. I guess the original request is already solved, but I leave this here if anyone needs the same thing.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rrd/workbox-backgroundsync-message